# Certain Characters in Foreign Languages Cause Lambda Post Invocation Errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invocation

When I query data from certain countries, namely Belarus, Bangladesh and Kazakhstan, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1679697735190] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 413.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 480, in <module>
main()
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 468, in main
handle_event_request(lambda_runtime_client,
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 148, in handle_event_request
lambda_runtime_client.post_invocation_result(invoke_id, result, result_content_type)
File "/var/runtime/lambda_runtime_client.py", line 62, in post_invocation_result
rapid_client.post_invocation_result(invoke_id, result_data if isinstance(result_data, bytes) else result_data.encode('utf-8'), content_type)
RuntimeError: Failed to post invocation response
equestId: c0f7e100-80b0-4e6a-84ff-9f5d0f8c708f Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1 Runtime.ExitError
```

I know this error usually has to do with the invocation response data being too large however even when only returning two or three results it errors out. I believe it has to do with the languages, for example Bangladesh's data is in Bangla. Is there something I can do to preprocess the data to keep the error from occuring?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: have you tried to encode the result in base64?

Comment: @Evgenii so the reason for this is because the amount of data in those different types of characters exceeds the limit. For example something in Bangla (Bengali) might look like 1 character but it carries roughly 30 times the amount of data as a latin character.